# Prove $\mathcal{L}_p[0,1]$ is separable using Lusin and Stone-Weierstrass theorems.

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

*1.* Prove that the set of $p$-integrable functions on $[0,1]$ with the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ is separable using Lusin's Theorem and the Stone Weierstrass Theorem.

*2.* Prove that $\mathcal{L}_\infty$ is not separable by constructing a set $\{x_\alpha : \alpha \in [0,1] \}\subset \mathcal{L}_\infty$ such that $||x_\alpha -x_\beta || =1$ if $\alpha\neq \beta$.

Attempt at *1*: Given $f\in \mathcal{L}_p$ I know from Lusin's theorem that there is an open set $E_f$ such that $\lambda(E_f)<\epsilon$ and $f|_{[0,1]\backslash E_f}$ is continuous. Since $[0,1]\backslash E_f$ is compact, from Stone-Weierstrass there is a polynomial $p_f$ defined on $[0,1]\backslash E_f$ (which we can safely assume has rational coefficients) such that 
$\sup_{[0,1]\backslash E_f}{|f(x)-p(x)|}<\epsilon.$

Now  we can extend the polynomial $p_f$ to all of $[0,1]$ by making it $0$ in $E_f$, and this new polynomial is in $\mathcal{L}_p$ since it is bounded in $[0,1]$.

Now: $$\|x-p\|^p_p=\int|f-p|^p d\lambda=\int_{[0,1]\backslash E_f}|f-p|^p d\lambda+\int_{E_f}|f|^p d\lambda.$$

I (believe) can make both terms on the right-hand side as small as desired. The problem is the that the polynomials with rational coefficients in a **given** set $E_f$ form a countable set, but for each $E_f$ I have a different polynomial, and I've got as many $E_f$ (and polynomials) as elements of $\mathcal{L}_p$. How can I make this countable?

Also, are there any mistakes in my attempt?

As to question number 2, I'm completely stumped and could use any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't put $p_f$ equal to zero in $E_f$, just keep the polynomial.

Comment: For question 2 consider $\chi_{[0,\alpha]}$, with $\alpha\in[0,1]$.

Comment: The polynomial is only defined on the compact set $[0,1]\backslash E_f$, which means I can't evaluate the norm of $f-p$ since said norm involves an integral over all of $[0,1]$

Comment: A polynomial is a polynomial, it is defined everywhere. What you don't have in $E_f$ is the property that $p_f$ approximates $f$ bettern than $<\epsilon$. But, on the other hand, you can use that the measure of $E_f$ is small to make your bounds work.

Comment: Ok, I get what you're saying now. You're absolutely right. My last problem is that I can't make the bounds on the integral over $E_f$ work: $\epsilon$ defines (through Lusin) $E_f$, which in turn defines $p$ and $|f-p|$, and thus the bound $M$ for the integrand. I can't take $\frac{\epsilon}{M}$ since I can't know $M$ beforehand.

Comment: I find it odd that this question asks you to use Lusin - it's much easier to use the density of $C_c^\infty(0,1)$ in $\mathcal L_p[0,1]$ for the reason you pointed out in your last comment.